# Loop inside a loop

Tags: javascript, timeout

Alright, so i need to run a timeout inside of a loop without recalling the loop all over again. The inner loop NEEDS to be a timeout.

```
(function loaded() {
for(var i=0;i<100; i++){
  if(!SOMECONDITION){
     setTimeout(loaded, 1);
  }
}
})();
```

This code almost works perfect except that if the condition is not met, it recalls the entire loop. I need it to only recall inside the loop like this.. but its not working.

```
    for(var i=0;i<100; i++){
(function loaded(i) {
      if(!SOMECONDITION){
         setTimeout(loaded, 1);
      }
})(i);
    }
```

the variable i must be able to be passed in the loop.

Comment: Why are you writing code this way?  It appears that you're trying to rapidly poll as fast as Javascript will let you for a condition to be true.  This is generally a bad way to program.  It will kill the battery life of a mobile device.  It hogs CPU cycles.  And, on top of all that, you're doing 100 of these at the same time.  This technique is simply way off base.  You need a better approach.

Comment: I don't know what the SOMECONDITION is that you're testing, but you should figure a way to create some sort of notification from whatever code changes that condition so you can directly be notified when the SOMECONDITION might have a different value.  Then, your code only needs to be in that notification handler and you won't be hammering the CPU and battery.  You can use a callback or a custom event or your own notification mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit complex, and someone might be able to simplify, but... I think you need two functions, one to capture `i` into a closure, one to have no arguments so it can be called as a timeout.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    function loaded() {
      if (!SOMECONDITION) {
        setTimeout(loaded, 1);
      }
    };
    loaded();
  })(i);
};
```

Comment: makes sense, but would the i variable be able to be accessed from within the conditional block?

Comment: The OP needs a better way to solve their problem without rapidly polling with 100 `setTimeout()` calls all trying to run at once.  I know you were literally trying to answer their coding question, but what they really need is a better approach to be notified when the condition might have changed and only check it then.  CPUs, batteries, other browser tabs, etc... will be much happier.

Comment: @jfriend00: Oh, I completely agree.

Comment: @Violet: Yes, it can. The argument of the outer anonymous function will be captured in the closure of the inner anonymous function. But do note issues raised by jfriend00 - this is a classic XY problem, there is very likely a better way to do what you ultimately want to do.

Comment: The code that i have provided Amadan is far from my actual code. The answer Amadan has provided. @jfriend, my goal is to actually have 100 timeout calls running at almost simultaneously

Comment: @Violet - And my feedback to you is that that is a bad design (100 timers running as quickly as possible).  If you explained the ACTUAL problem you're trying to solve, we could likely help you find a good design.  I consider it our job here on SO to not only help with the literal question asked, but to also counsel folks when they're going in a bad direction and there are likely better ways to solve their problem without the consequences of the path they're on.  If you choose to ignore that type of advice, that is your choice (not wise in my opinion, but your choice).

Comment: Well the actual code is quite long, and any kind of snippet would be very hard to understand. I am using OOP style, but i am trying to find a solution that will check if the resources from an object have been loaded (when it has been loaded a function sets a property of the object to true). if the object is not loaded, i want the function to sleep until it is loaded. my original code worked well, but i just found out its actually running the else ! condition several times, causing unnecessary processing.

Comment: in short, thinking about it now. i just need to do a simple sleep function

Comment: In short, you need events. Whatever you're trying to load in the browser environment will let you bind an event listener to notify you if and when it is loaded. Don't set a property to true when a resource loads, execute whatever needs to be executed then and there, or set into motion some other event or timeout that will call back when you need it to, or force a promise, or something similar. JavaScript should not be executing when nothing is going on; there is no sleep function.

Comment: yes i know there is no sleep function :P, How i solved my problem was a little tricky. i made my function inherit Amadan's idea, but instead of making it use a local variable for that function (which was an entire other problem). What i have done is efficient. The the reason the object contains a property for if its loaded is because the item can be unloaded and reloaded several times. So instead of doing that i hold the resource in a variable and loaded just says, yep we still have the resource. if it doesn't then i just reload it.